# sublist with boundary limiters as elements

Tags: list, prolog, predicate, dcg

I have a basic predicate for list like this:

```
sublist(List, Offset, Length, Sublist)

sublist(List, Offset, Length, Sublist):-
    length(Prefix, Offset),
    append(Prefix, Rest, List),
    length(Sublist, Length),
    append(Sublist, _, Rest).
```

which returns a sublist from the first element in initial list for a given length.

```
6 ?- sublist([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], 3, 6, X).
X = [d, e, f, g, h, i].
```

I want to transform this predicate with a lower and upper bounds which is directly the element of the original list, like this

```
sublist([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], d, i, X).
X = [d, e, f, g, h, i].
```

how to do this?

Comment: my code is only with built in predicate .

Comment: What do you want for results for something like, `sublist([a,b,c,d,e,f,d,j,k,i,x,p,i,z], d, i, X)`?

Comment: What do you expect for `sublist([d,d,i,i], d, i, X)`?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a simple "transformation" of the existing code, but this is ideally handled using DCG:

```
% subseq(S, First, Last) succeeds if S is a subsequence of the input
%   sequence and starts with First and ends with Last.
%   The subsequence is defined as an arbitrary sequence (...)
%   followed by the desired subsequence, followed by another arbitrary sequence
%
subseq([First|T], First, Last) --> ..., seq([First|T], Last), ... .

% seq(S, X) defines any sequence that ends with X
%
seq([X], X) --> [X].
seq([H|T], X) --> [H], seq(T, X).

% ... defines an arbitrary sequence of zero or more input elements
%
... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .

% sublist(L, First, Last, S) succeeds if S is a subsequence of L that
%   starts with First and ends with Last. It works by calling the DCG
%   defined above.
%
sublist(L, First, Last, S) :- phrase(subseq(S, First, Last), L).
```

Resulting in:

```
| ?- sublist([a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], d, i, S).

S = [d,e,f,g,h,i] ? a

no

| ?- sublist([a,b,d,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], d, i, S).

S = [d,c,d,e,f,g,h,i] ? a

S = [d,e,f,g,h,i]

no
| ?-
```

---

As an aside, `subseq//3` could be slightly rewritten as:

```
subseq([First|T], First, Last) --> seq(_, First), seq(T, Last), ... .
```

Comment: @DanielLyons I added comments to explain the code. I am using `...` in this case as the name for an arbitrary sequence, which Prolog allows (`...` is a valid predicate name).

Comment: s(X). I love you. So much.

Comment: Ok I understood. Thanks you all.

Comment: Minor: why do you exclude the empty sequence in `seq//2`?

Comment: @false because by design `seq/2` needs to succeed only if there is a "last element" seen in the sequence (thus, the second argument), and the empty sequence has no last element.

Comment: @lurker: `seq_last//2`?

Comment: @false yeah that would be a more apt name.

Answer (score 3):

A `sublist` predicate which seems to conform to your specification:

```
take([], _, []).
take([End|_], End, [End]).
take([El|L], End, [El|More]) :-
    take(L, End, More).

drop([], _, []).
drop([Start|L], Start, [Start|L]).
drop([_|L], Start, Out) :-
    drop(L, Start, Out).

sublist(L, Start, End, Out) :-
    drop(L, Start, Out1),
    take(Out1, End, Out).
```

Output:

```
?- sublist([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], d, i, X).

X = [d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

*Explanation*. First we drop elements from the list until we hit the element we want the sublist to start with, then we take elements from the remaining elements until we hit the element we want the sublist to end with.

Comment: Thanks it works. even if I don't understand the code. Why to drop before ?

Comment: I added a little bit of explanation, is it clearer now?

Comment: it is clearer. Even if I have difficulty to understand the logic.  Why to "drop" elements from the list and not directly select the given elements .

Comment: If you reorder your arguments so that `End` and `Start` are first, you can replace `sublist/4` with this DCG construct: `sublist(Start, End) --> drop(Start), take(End).`.

Comment: @user1125932: I am not a very experienced prolog programmer, this seemed to me the easiest solution to your question! That's why I drop elements and don't "select" the ones I want.

Answer (score 2):

append/3 it's a flexible predicate, can be used to define prefixes,suffixes, etc...

```
sublist(Ls, F, L, Es) :-
    append(_, [F|Fs], Ls),
    append(Ts, [L|_], Fs),
    append([F|Ts], [L], Es).
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on modifying your existing code, you can do this:

```
sublist(List, Start, Stop, Sublist):-
    % compute the indices
    nth0(Offset, List, Start),
    nth0(EndOffset,  List, Stop),
    Length is EndOffset - Offset + 1,

    % original predicate
    length(Prefix, Offset),
    append(Prefix, Rest, List),
    length(Sublist, Length),
    append(Sublist, _, Rest).
```

I would probably consider it better to move the calculation into another predicate though.

I strongly prefer @adamse's approach, especially if you reorder the arguments so that `Start` and `End` come first, because that enables a DCG implementation. The lack of arithmetic means it will be possible to drive the predicate in different directions.

**Edit**: it's impossible not to admire @lurker's solution, which is just absolutely beautiful and a great reminder of why we love Prolog.